# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - Dojo "onclick" event is not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dojo, onclick, ibm-mobilefirst

When trying our Worklight application in both Firefox and Chrome we noticed that on Chrome the `onclick` event on an item of our `EdgeToEdgeStoreList` does not work.
In Firefox the `onclick` event does work.

```
require([ "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList", "dojo/_base/array" ], function(Memory,
        EdgeToEdgeStoreList, array) {

var conferencesJson = [];
for(var i = 0; i < conference.array.length; i++){
    var x = {"label" :  conference.array[i].name,
            "moveTo" : "dayOverview",
            "onclick" : "test()"
    };
    conferencesJson.push(x);
}

    var conferenceStore = new Memory({
        data : conferencesJson,
        idProperty : "label"
    });
    var conferenceList = new EdgeToEdgeStoreList({
        store : conferenceStore
    }, "conferenceList");

    conferenceList.startup();
});
```

In our HTML we just have an unordered list.

```
<ul id="conferenceList"></ul>
```

Can someone explain why this works in Firefox and doesn't work in Chrome?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here..Check your conferencesJson variable for proper JSON syntax.  An extra comma at the end always trips up IE but not Firefox..Not sure about Chrome...Also, try adding conferenceList.placeAt("conferenceList"); just before startup();

Comment: I found the answer to this problem.
I replaced this piece of code:
    var x = {"label" :  conference.array[i].name,
            "moveTo" : "dayOverview",
            "onclick" : "test()"
    };

with:
    var x = {"label" :  conference.array[i].name,
            "moveTo" : "dayOverview",
            "onClick" : test
    };

I made few changes to the onClick:
- capital C
- test without quotes and brackets

Comment: stylistically I make a habit of using array.map but onClick is the dijit way.  conferencesJson = array.map(conference.array, function (i) { return {label: i.name, moveTo: "dayOverview", onClick: test });

Comment: Yes onClick (capital C) is the correct name. Glenn could you answer your own post with the official answer maybe, so the question does not appear as unanswered? Thanks!

Comment: @GlennObyn, could you please follow edurocher's suggestion above?

Answer (score 0):

As Glenn is not adding the answer... here it is:

Replace this piece of code:
`var x = {"label" : conference.array[i].name, "moveTo" : "dayOverview", "onclick" : "test()" };`

With:
`var x = {"label" : conference.array[i].name, "moveTo" : "dayOverview", "onClick" : test };`.

The diff is the capital `C` in `onClick`.